# Generator Json Schema .NET - Loading External References from Files

Tags: .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am about to write a generator, which gets a starting directory as input and from this location it opens every folder and creates concatenated json schemas.

```
File 1: ValidResponse.json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "ValidResponse",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Head": {
            "type": "object",
            "CommonResponse": {"$ref":"CommonHeader.json"},
            "required":["CommonResponse"]
        },
        "Body": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required":["Head","Body"]
}

File 2: CommonHeader.json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "CommonHeader",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "RequestArguments": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DataCollection": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "DeviceClass": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Scope": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "DeviceId": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "Status": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Code": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Reason": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "UserMessage": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "Code",
        "Reason",
        "UserMessage"
      ]
    },
    "Timestamp": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "RequestArguments",
    "Status",
    "Timestamp"
  ]
}
```

Now what i want with this 2 Files is, to load File 1 - ValidResponse as a schema and at the "$ref..." it should load File 2 - CommonHeader and therefore creating 1 big json schema, while being able to still manipulate the files on its own, not having to worry about breaking the whole code.

I am already using the Newtonsoft Nugget Package and can validate json schemas, but the referencing part just dont want to work

```
_jsonValidResponse = File.ReadAllText(_baseUri + @"\ObjectStructureOfValidResponse.json");
_jsonString = File.ReadAllText(_baseUri+@"\jsonstring.json");
JObject jsonString = JObject.Parse(_jsonString);
JSchema jsonSchemaValidResponse = JSchema.Parse(_jsonValidResponse);
jsonString.IsValid(jsonschemaValidResponse)
```

Whats the "magic" here to get this references to load during runtime?

Comment: Are you open to using a different JSON Schema implementation?  If so, you can try [Manatee.Json](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json).  (I'm the author.)